# Command line args from cmdline vs in IDE

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

The following code behaves as expected if I run this from the actual command line (i.e. javac ..., java XXX.java (args[0]) (args[1]).

However if I try to set the command line args through eclipse I get the "Error with input or output file" error, but if the cmd line args in eclipse lenght != 2 I also get the "Must specify input file...." so I know it is assigning them

Does anyone know what the deal is with this?

```
public class main {

    public static Scanner fileScanner(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fName));
    }

    public static PrintStream printStream(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fName));
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan=null;
    PrintStream out=null;


    if(args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Must specify input file & output file on cmd line");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    try {
        scan = fileScanner(args[0]);
        out = printStream(args[1]);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error with input or output file");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Since you're passing in filenames, are you passing in absolute paths? I suspect eclipse is using a different working directory than you are when you run from the command line so it can't find the file if you're passing in a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I tried you program, it works fine in eclipse when i give filename with complete path.

```
package so.ch1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */


         public static Scanner fileScanner(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException {
                return new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fName));
              }

        public static PrintStream printStream(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException {
                return new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(fName));
              }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan=null;
            PrintStream out=null;


            if(args.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Must specify input file & output file on cmd line");
                System.exit(0);
            }


            try {
                scan = fileScanner(args[0]);
                out = printStream(args[1]);
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error with input or output file");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
}
```

Args given: F:/temp/abc.txt F:/temp/xyz.txt